# Different colors for error bars Matlab 2014b

Tags: matlab, colors

I am plotting error bars and would like to color each error bar in different colors in order to make the plot a bit easier to interpret. However, since I am using matlab2014b, everything online is outdated since the error bar series does not have children anymore. This is the code I am using:

```
x=[1 2 3 4]
y=[0.5 0.3 0.45 0.36]
upperbound=y.*0.25
lowerbound=y.*0.15

fig1=figure  
e1=errorbar(x,y,lowerbound,upperbound,'x')
```

If possible I would like to color the center point as well, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could plot each error bar individually, for example:

```
hold on
for k = 1:length(x)
    e1 = errorbar(x(k),y(k),lowerbound(k),upperbound(k),'x');
    set(e1,'Color',rand(1,3))
    set(e1,'MarkerEdgeColor',rand(1,3))
end
```

See [Errorbar Series Properties](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/errorbarseries-properties.html) for more information on how to change line styles, colors etc.